# 'BasicCompany' could not be found when importing "Dev03-Clothing Company-FileSet4"

Tags: training-certification

I'm following the Sitecore training **Developer's Fundamentals 9.3 Collection**, **Album 3**, **Single 3: Construct the Website Pages Using the Components**

In the end of the single there is a solution project called "Dev03-Clothing Company-FileSet4". I am trying to import it but I get the error.

[image]

I tried to include **add namespace = BasicCompany** under Views/web.config and inside root web.config but no help.

The only dll with that name I found is **BasicCompany.Web.dll** inside C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ClothingCo.local.test\bin. I added it as reference but still no help.

My Sitecore version is 9.2 instead of 9.3 could that be the problem?

- .Net Framework is 4.7.2
- Properties -> Build -> Test,
  passes all the Sitecore TDS build
  settings test

Comment: You should not use C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ClothingCo.local.test\bin folder as reference for assemblies.

Comment: Did you ever fix this @ffomar?